# Incompatible types. Required android.support.v4.content Loader

Tags: android

[image]

I am trying to implement a Loader in my project, but I can't return the new CustomLoader in the onCreateLoader() method. I've attached the screenshot below:

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code of your BookLoader Class?

Comment: Your `BookLoader` might be extending from `android.content.Loader` instead of `android.support.v4.content.Loader`